# $_GET contains empty string when using jQuery ajax get request

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Javascript

```
$("#appendedInputButton").click( function () {
    bday = document.getElementById("appendedInputButton").value;
    $.get("php/getWiki.php", {
        "bday":bday
    }, function (data) {
        response = data;
    })
});
```

Also tried bday w/o the quotes.

PHP

```
if (isset($_GET["bday"])) {
    var_dump($_GET);
    $bday = $_GET["bday"];
    echo $bday;
    echo "<br>";
    ...
} else {
    echo "error lols."
}
```

I guess I'm not doing something correctly.
Here is the response outout:

```
response
"array(1) {
    ["bday"]=>
    string(0) ""
}"
```

Comment: Is `appendedInputButton` value an empty string?

Comment: No it's not.  It is a date input which holds a value something like "2012-12-25" when you call `document.getElementById("appendedInputButton").value;`

Comment: I think you meant to get the value of the element that contains the birthday, not the button that’s been clicked.

Comment: @minitech Sorry for the confusion but that is the id of the input that holds the bday not the button. `<input class="span6" id="appendedInputButton" type="date">`.

Comment: @icanc: Well, you’re binding the `click` event to it, so maybe it’s being sent *before* you type anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding the `click` event to the same input that contains the value, so the first time you click it, there won’t be anything in it to send.

<sub>(Just posting this as an answer so it’s actually answered ^_^)</sub>